# PowerShell command for burning iso on Windows XP?

Tags: powershell, iso, dvd-burning

I need to know can I use PowerShell to burn ISO file on windows XP without any other addition software like MagicISO or others? I mean .NET framework is on top of Windows XP.
So if it is possible, then I need to know which commands allows me to do such a job?
Especially I need a command, not a whole script.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this link: [Burning and Erasing CD/DVD/Blu-ray Media with C# and IMAPI2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24544/Burning-and-Erasing-CD-DVD-Blu-ray-Media-with-C-an) has sample code. It also has a link to the Update required to use this API on XP. Overall, it appears that a SHIM is required and it's all done using a an interop library whose source is included at the referenced link.